# Why css works in JSFiddle but not in my App/Site

Tags: css

First: it's commercial software, I can't share a link to it so you can see what's happening. Ugh. Makes everything harder.

I've written a block of css for print purposes. Here were my steps:

1. Load page in application
2. copy HTML from developer tools
3. Paste html into jsfiddle (so, all the classes/structure is there properly)
4. write the css in jsfiddle--stuff looks like I want it to look
5. copy css from jsfiddle into my inquiryPrint.css file (the file that loads for printing)
6. SOME of the css works, some of it doesn't

Things I considered:

- An override issue; inquiryPrint.css is the last file loaded, it should apply its overrides last
- The print css file isn't invoked only on media type of print...in fact, here it is:

  ```
  printWindow.document.write('&lt;link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/InquiryPrint.css" type="text/css" /&gt;');
  ```
- This is the most important, I think: the site is picking up SOME of the valid CSS selectors from the inquiryPrint.css file, but not ALL of them; e.g., it sees .row and applies it's CSS, but doesn't see .admItem and apply its CSS. And this is the stuff that works correctly in the jsfiddle--i.e. .admItem works in jsfiddle but not my app.

Things I tried:

- Close/reopen
- chrome hard refresh (cmd-shift-R)
- it's shared code; I
  pushed my changes up to our dev environment, pulled them down on a
  co-worker's page, and validated it's not working on his computer
  either.

## Update

1. This isn't an override issue. We've even reduced/stripped out all other css files and the problem persists.
2. This isn't a specificity issue with complex selectors. Almost every selector is single-tier/level (see examples).
3. This isn't a browser issue. It does not work in Chrome or Firefox (although, of course, those two pages render slightly different).
4. I had originally cut/paste from jsfiddle, so I thought it might be a cut/paste issue. It's not--we we-wrote the classes by hand with no fix.
5. It's not a spelling issue, we've tested it by replacing '.admItem' with '.georgeItem' and cut/paste that into the correct place, didn't fix it.
6. Again, it's seeing OTHER content from the file, just not THIS content.
7. We stripped the whole css file empty, just left one class, it still didn't pick it up.
8. I put embedded CSS into the head of the HTML file, it is not picking that up either, for this one class, but it IS picking up other values we put there (e.g. body text transform: uppercase).
9. We can click through developer tools and see the correct css file, with the correct current changes so it shouldn't be a pointer/syntax issue--it sees the file is there, and picks SOME values from it, not others.

A few screenshots:

### Chrome Developer Tools

[image: chrome developer tools]

### The Embedded CSS

[image: embedded css]

Here is the css file in its entirety. 
.georgeItem {
      text-transform:lowercase!important;
    }

```
.admItem {
    display:-webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction:row;
    -webkit-justify-content:flex-start;
}

.heading {
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 10px 0px;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}
h2 {
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}
h3 {
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}
h4 {
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}
h5 {
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  color: #4c7a87;
}
h6 {
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #66909c;
}
p {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 0 0 5px 0;
  color: #515151;
}
em {
  font-style: italic;
}
strong {
  font-weight: 700;
}
pre em {
  font-style: italic;
  color: #686667;
}

.inquiryPrint {
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS',Helvetica,sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-size: 1rem;
}


* {
  background: transparent !important;
  color: black !important;
  text-shadow: none !important;
  filter: none !important;
  -ms-filter: none !important;
}
/* Black prints faster: h5bp.com/s */
a,
a:visited {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
a[href]:after {
  content: " (" attr(href) ")";
}
abbr[title]:after {
  content: " (" attr(title) ")";
}
.ir a:after,
a[href^="javascript:"]:after,
a[href^="#"]:after {
  content: "";
}
/* Don't show links for images, or javascript/internal links */
pre,
blockquote {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
thead {
  display: table-header-group;
}
/* h5bp.com/t */
tr,
img {
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}
img {
  max-width: 100% !important;
}
@page  {
  margin: 0.5cm;
  size: landscape;/*does not work in some browsers like chrome */
}
p,
h2,
h3 {
  orphans: 3;
  widows: 3;
}
h2,
h3 {
  page-break-after: avoid;
}
.inquiryPrint table {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.inquiryPrint tr,
.inquiryPrint thead tr,
.inquiryPrint tbody tr,
tr,
th,
td {
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}
.inquiryPrint tr th,
.inquiryPrint thead tr th {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #c0c0c0;
  padding: 5px;
}
.inquiryPrint tr,
.inquiryPrint tbody tr {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #c0c0c0;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.inquiryPrint tr:last-child,
.inquiryPrint tbody tr:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
.inquiryPrint tr td {
  padding: 5px 10px 10px 2px;
  text-align: center;
}
.inquiryPrint tr td,
.inquiryPrint tbody tr td {
  text-align: center;
}
.inquiryPrint tr td.right,
.inquiryPrint tr th.right,
.inquiryPrint tbody tr td.right,
.inquiryPrint thead tr th.right {
  text-align: right;
}
.inquiryPrint tr td.left,
.inquiryPrint tr th.left,
.inquiryPrint tbody tr td.left,
.inquiryPrint thead tr th.left {
  text-align: left;
}
/*.inquiryPrint tr td.totalRow,
.inquiryPrint tbody tr td.totalRow {
  text-align: right;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-size: 1rem;
}*/
/* supports 15 character value with padding */
.inquiryPrint .wide15 {
  width: 100px;
}
/* supports 30 character value with padding */
.inquiryPrint .wide30 {
  width: 200px;
}

/* trying to insert code conversion to flexbox for printing clinical order only */
.head {
    display:-webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction:column;
    -webkit-justify-content:flex-start;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

.value {
  display:-webkit-inline-flex;
}

.row {
    display:-webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction:row;
    -webkit-justify-content:flex-start;
}

.admItem {
    display:-webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction:row;
    -webkit-justify-content:flex-start;
}

.head .row {
    display:-webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction:column;
    -webkit-justify-content:flex-start;
}

.admLabel,.label,.label_left {
    text-align:left;
  font-family:Arial;
  font-weight:700;
  font-size:1em;
    margin-right:3px;
}


.row.pushRight {
    text-align:right;
    -webkit-flex-direction:row;
    -webkit-justify-content:flex-end;
    justify-content:flex-end;
}

.admPatientDetails .row {
    margin-top:20px;
    display:-webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction:row;
    -webkit-justify-content:space-between;
}

.clinicalOrderLineAdministrationDetails table {
    width:100%;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

.clinicalOrderLineAdministrationDetails table tbody tr {
    border-bottom:1px dotted #818181;
}

.admItem {
    display:-webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction:row;
    -webkit-justify-content:flex-start;
}
```

Comment: Are your results browser dependent? e.g. does it work in Chrome but not IE?  Also note (in IE) that if you are rendering off of your local environment (or a server in your Intranet) IE's Compatibility View settings may be *forcing* you into compatibility mode where as jsfiddle won't.

Comment: Order is not the only way to determine what CSS rule will apply, specificity and the `!important` flag also play their part. As mentioned, FireBug, the Chrome developer tools or IE's `F12` tools will be the best way to see what the resultant CSS is that's applying to your elements.

Comment: can you paste a bit of the CSS... you can change values if you like, and anonymize any CSS class names & ID's... maybe there is some minor detail that we can catch that is the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

We found the issue last night. The way we were dynamically generating the page in javascript, there wasn't a doctype declaration at the top of the page. Once we added

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "htt p://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Everything worked fine. Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

> the site is picking up SOME of the valid CSS selectors from the inquiryPrint.css file, but not ALL of them; e.g., it sees .row and applies it's CSS, but doesn't see .admItem and apply its CSS. And this is the stuff that works correctly in the jsfiddle--i.e. .admItem works in jsfiddle but not my app.

That sounds as if the other stylesheets, that are not targeted at any medium specifically, override the rules you have in your print stylesheet by using more specific selectors.

Comment: Well, you’re giving us not much to go on, although thanks for the update you added to your question. So, next shot in the dark: Have you validated your print css file? No syntactically incorrect selectors that might make browsers skip a complete rule, no missing curly brackets, …?

Answer (score 0):

Using a tool like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) you'll be able to see which CSS rules are being applied and why they're overriding other styles.

As CBroe states, it's quite likely that CSS styles with more specific selectors are overriding your stylesheet. Clearly your stylesheet is being read, so that's not the issue.

Comment: OK, so let me clarify, I realize I left this information out. Looking in Developer Tools, I can see that it isn't being overridden by a different class.